# uii2 Kartik format decimal attribute

Tags: excel, yii2, export

Hello i'm using kartik exportMenu to export in excel a dataprovider.

When i set
`format=['decimal',2]`, in de excel output print **'20,00** i dont know wy print the
" **'** " before number,
if I change it to `format=integer` dosen't print the " **'** " just 20.

help please.

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/86199/how-to-remove-single-quote-in-front-of-numbers-in-a-cell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'autoXlFormat'=>true 
> 'enableAutoFormat'=> false 
> 'enableFormatter'=> false

```
 echo  ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumn,
            'autoXlFormat'=> true,
            'enableAutoFormat'=> false,
            'enableFormatter'=> false,
        ]);
```